# How to show alert dialog box in a activity?

Tags: android

How can i show a alert message in an activity?
I had parse the value by volley and i needed a alert dialog box when there is an error. 
I can do it in fragment properly but how to do in activity?

Comment: If you can in fragment, then why not in activity??

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly you mean but, I use Toast. More at:
[Toast Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html)

[Example of usage Toast](http://www.caveofprogramming.com/guest-articles/toast-message-or-error-message/)

In case you want to use Dialogs just do it this way.

```
void openDialog()
{
   AlerDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
   alert.setMessage("Error.");
   alert.alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("OK", 
      new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

         @Override
         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            //ToDO
         }
      });
    alert.setNegativeButton("NO/Cancel", 
      new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

         @Override
         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            //ToDo
         }
      });

      AlertDialog dialog = alert.create();
      dialog.show();
}
```

Comment: I too used toast but i need a alert message dialog box

Answer (score 0):

you can use [Toasts](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html) to alert the user about something.

but since you talking about errors ,that will lead to app crashing, exceptions and handlers are a better way to keep your app running.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an alert dialog.

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setTitle("Error Occurred")
    .setMessage("Are you sure you want to continue?")
    .setPositiveButton("yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
            // continue with task
        }
     })
    .setNegativeButton("no", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
            // do the needful
        }
     })
    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
    .show();
```

You can also set a neutral button using *setNeutralButton()*.

OR

If you just want to show a message to the user, use Toast instead. Create a toast object.

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "message", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
```

Here *Toast.LENGTH_LONG* is the duration for which toast will be visible. You can also use *Toast.LENGTH_SHORT* as duration.

Show it.

```
toast.show();
```

By default, toast appears at the bottom of the screen. You can change it's gravity.

```
toast.setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.LEFT, 0, 0);
```

You can also create custom toast view and set it using *setView()* method.